# Java Pattern stuck on simple regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match SQL SELECT queries using regex patterns in Java:

```
(\bselect\b.*?\b(table_name)\b.*?\bfrom\b.*?\b(column_name)\b).*?((\bwhere\b)|(order\s+by))
```

If I use this pattern to search a text file in any other editor (Sublime Text, VS Code, Notepad++ etc.), it's able to match and find text. However, if I use the same pattern in Java's Pattern matcher, it seems to freeze and not match anything. Is there something wrong with the regex pattern itself?

Java:

```
Pattern p_select = Pattern.compile(String.format("(\\bselect\\b.*?\\b(table_name)\\b.*?\\bfrom\\b.*?\\b(column_name)\\b).*?((\\bwhere\\b)|(order\\s+by))", column, table), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m_select = p_select.matcher(text);
if (m_select.find()) {
    ...
}
```

The string (variable `text`) that is being matched against is very long (90,000+ characters). I found that trimming down the string makes the pattern search "work" again, but the string can't be trimmed. Is there any way to make Java's Pattern matcher work on this string the way other editor's are able to?

Comment: Could you share a small version of the string? One that can break your code for us to evaluate?

Comment: There is no specific string. I found that bringing the 90,000 character string down to ~60,000 makes the matcher work again. Anything above it freezes.

Comment: What are the exact rules? The problem is with numerous `.*?`. If you can precise these patterns, especially those on the left, the regex will be less prone to timeout issues.

Comment: Also you can try using Google [re2](https://github.com/google/re2j), it is much faster, but has its limitations compared to Java's `Pattern`